# Count all possible combinations no matter the column order

Tags: r, dplyr, count, data.table

I have a dataset which looks like

```
df <- data.frame(rbind(c("A","B","D",NA,NA,NA,3),
c("B","A","D","C",NA,NA,1),
c("B","C","E","A","D",NA,5),
c("A","B",NA,NA,NA,NA,4),
c("A","B","C","D","E","F",2)))


    X1      X2       X3        X4       X5        X6    N
    A        B        D        NA       NA        NA    3 
    B        A        D        C        NA        NA    1 
    B        C        E        A         D        NA    5 
    A        B        NA       NA       NA        NA    4 
    A        B        C        D         E         F    2
```

Where the column *N* is the number of times that combination happens.

and I want like to have a cumulative sum by unordered columns (no matter on which column the letter is located) such that:

```
     X1      X2       X3        X4       X5        X6     N
    A       NA        NA       NA        NA        NA     15
    B       NA        NA       NA        NA        NA     15
    C       NA        NA       NA        NA        NA     8
    D       NA        NA       NA        NA        NA     11
    E       NA        NA       NA        NA        NA     7
    F       NA        NA       NA        NA        NA     2
    A        B        NA       NA        NA        NA     15 
    A        B        C        NA        NA        NA     8 
    A        B        C        D         NA        NA     8 
    A        B        C        D         E         NA     7 
    A        B        C        D         E         F      1 
    B        C        NA       NA        NA        NA     8
    ....
```

So the idea is to have all possible combinations and the frequency but taking into account that the order of appearance in Column is not relevant.

Comment: why column `N` is `3,1,5,4,2`? could you explain a bit?

Comment: Those numbers are the frequency of that specific combination. For instance in the desired data frame, the combination (A,B,C) has an N=8 because it's the sum of N that happen to have these three letters e.g. (B,A,D,C) + (B,C,E,A,D) + (A,B,C,D,E,F) = 1 + 5 + 2 = 8.

Comment: Not directly about the question: By calling `rbind`, you've made a matrix rather than a data frame, so your column N is coerced to character, and then `data.frame` by default turns character columns (in this case, *all* your columns) to factors. So now `N` is a factor trying to represent a number. No need for `rbind`; just put the vectors all in a data frame

Comment: Sorry, I misread the purpose of `rbind`. It's actually by creating vectors of mixed types (string and numeric) that you've turned your counts into strings, which are later turned into factors. Don't want to derail too much but do want to point out data type issues that may come up

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach that generates a list of the combinations of the values by row adds it to the original dataframe, unnests and tallies N by group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(comblist = apply(.[1:6], 1, function(x) {
    x <- sort(na.omit(x))
    unlist(sapply(seq_along(x), function(y)
      list(combn(x, y,
        FUN = function(l)
          list(toString(l))
      ))))
  })) %>%
  select(comblist, N) %>%
  unnest(comblist) %>%
  group_by(comblist) %>%
  summarise(x = sum(N))

# A tibble: 63 x 2
   comblist             N
   <chr>            <dbl>
 1 A                   15
 2 A, B                15
 3 A, B, C              8
 4 A, B, C, D           8
 5 A, B, C, D, E        7
 6 A, B, C, D, E, F     2
 7 A, B, C, D, F        2
 8 A, B, C, E           7
 9 A, B, C, E, F        2
10 A, B, C, F           2
# ... with 53 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution

```
l <- Map(function(x) c(na.omit(x)),data.frame(t(df[1:6]),stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
lout <- Map(function(x) c(na.omit(x)),data.frame(t(dfout),stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

dfout$N <- sapply(lout, function(x) sum(as.numeric(df$X7)[sapply(l, function(v) all(x %in% v))]))
```

such that

```
> dfout
   X1   X2   X3   X4   X5   X6  N
1   A <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 15
2   B <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 15
3   C <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  8
4   D <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 11
5   E <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  7
6   F <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  2
7   A    B <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 15
8   A    B    C <NA> <NA> <NA>  8
9   A    B    C    D <NA> <NA>  8
10  A    B    C    D    E <NA>  7
11  A    B    C    D    E    F  2
12  B    C <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  8
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), X3 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, NA, 
1L), .Label = c("C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), X4 = structure(c(NA, 
2L, 1L, NA, 3L), .Label = c("A", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    X5 = structure(c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, 2L), .Label = c("D", "E"
    ), class = "factor"), X6 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L
    ), .Label = "F", class = "factor"), X7 = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 5L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

dfout <- structure(list(X1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B"), X2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "C"), X3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "C", 
"C", "C", "C", NA), X4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "D", 
"D", "D", NA), X5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "E", 
"E", NA), X6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "F", 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The `dfout` you posted is just a subset of the total rows, right?

Comment: @camille I just copied from the OP's post, not generated from my code. My code just computes `N` column

Comment: Oh, okay. But isn't getting the combinations of A...F part of the task as well, not just adding up their occurrences?

Comment: @camille I am not sure if OP need to generate all those combinations, or just wants the occurrences with respect to given combinations....but I guess yours is the former one

Answer (score 1):

An option using `RcppAlgos::comboGeneral` to generate combinations and `data.table::cube` to (quoting from `?cube`) *Calculate aggregates at various levels of groupings producing multiple (sub-)totals.*:

```
library(data.table)
library(RcppAlgos)

v <- unique(unlist(df[-ncol(df)]))
v <- sort(v[!is.na(v)])
nc <- length(v)

DT <- melt(setDT(df)[, rn:=.I], id.vars=c("rn", "X7"), na.rm=TRUE, variable.factor=FALSE)
combi <- DT[, as.data.table(do.call(rbind, lapply(1L:.N, function(m) {
    rcom <- comboGeneral(value, m)
    M <- matrix("", nrow=nrow(rcom), ncol=nc)

    M[cbind(rep(1L:nrow(rcom), ncol(rcom)), match(rcom, v))] <- rcom
    M
}))), .(rn, COUNT=as.integer(X7))]
ans <- cube(combi, .(COUNT=sum(COUNT)), by=paste0("V", 1:6))
setorderv(ans[complete.cases(ans)], paste0("V", 6:1))[]
```

output:

```
    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 COUNT
 1:  A                   15
 2:     B                15
 3:  A  B                15
 4:        C              8
 5:  A     C              8
 6:     B  C              8
 7:  A  B  C              8
 8:           D          11
 9:  A        D          11
10:     B     D          11
11:  A  B     D          11
12:        C  D           8
13:  A     C  D           8
14:     B  C  D           8
15:  A  B  C  D           8
16:              E        7
17:  A           E        7
18:     B        E        7
19:  A  B        E        7
20:        C     E        7
21:  A     C     E        7
22:     B  C     E        7
23:  A  B  C     E        7
24:           D  E        7
25:  A        D  E        7
26:     B     D  E        7
27:  A  B     D  E        7
28:        C  D  E        7
29:  A     C  D  E        7
30:     B  C  D  E        7
31:  A  B  C  D  E        7
32:                 F     2
33:  A              F     2
34:     B           F     2
35:  A  B           F     2
36:        C        F     2
37:  A     C        F     2
38:     B  C        F     2
39:  A  B  C        F     2
40:           D     F     2
41:  A        D     F     2
42:     B     D     F     2
43:  A  B     D     F     2
44:        C  D     F     2
45:  A     C  D     F     2
46:     B  C  D     F     2
47:  A  B  C  D     F     2
48:              E  F     2
49:  A           E  F     2
50:     B        E  F     2
51:  A  B        E  F     2
52:        C     E  F     2
53:  A     C     E  F     2
54:     B  C     E  F     2
55:  A  B  C     E  F     2
56:           D  E  F     2
57:  A        D  E  F     2
58:     B     D  E  F     2
59:  A  B     D  E  F     2
60:        C  D  E  F     2
61:  A     C  D  E  F     2
62:     B  C  D  E  F     2
63:  A  B  C  D  E  F     2
    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 COUNT
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do and it would be helpful to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) as well as an **expected** example. That way you can help others to help you! But if you want the counts for the letters in **any** and **all** columns:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
pivot_longer(cols =everything()) %>%
group_by(value) %>%
summarise(N = n())
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added a small example of how the data looks like in R. The whole idea is to count occurrences of each element (A, B, C...). So for instance, the individuals in the first row will contribute to the groups (A), (B), (D), (A,B), (A,D), (B,D), (A,B,D), matter what the order of the columns is.